# Surface Integral Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this question:

Evaluate $\int r . dS$ over the surface of a sphere, radius a, centred at the origin.

I'm not really sure what '$r$' is supposed to be? I would guess a position vector? If so, I would have $r . dS$ as $(asin\theta cos\phi, a sin\theta sin\phi, acos\theta) . (a^2sin\theta d\theta d\phi)$ which doesn't seem right. Any pointers appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you copied this right? Is $r$ a vector function?

Comment: Yes, word-for-word. The r and dS are in bold, so I think that suggests r is a vector function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to look at this.  For both ways, though, the notation $r \cdot dS$ is a shorthand for $r \cdot n dS$, where $n$ is the normal vector to $S$, pointed outward.  In this case, the normal vector is just the position vector $r$, normalized to unit length.  Thus the surface integral is simply

$$a \int_S dS = 4 \pi a^3$$

This may also be analyzed using the divergence theorem.  Because $\nabla \cdot r = 3$, we have the surface integral equal to

$$3 \int_{\text{sphere}} dV = 4 \pi a^3$$

Comment: I know you're explaining this properly I'm just struggling to see how it boils down to $a\int_S ds$. Maybe I need to think on it.

Comment: It's just the the dot product of the radius vector and the outward normal to the surface is just the length of the radius, $a$.  It is constant, so you pull it out of the surface integral and just get the surface area.

Comment: Fully visualised by the answer below, thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy, you don't even need to change coordinates or anything of this kind. Just note that at each point of the sphere the normal unit vector $n$ points outwards, so he is radially pointing away from the sphere. However, the position vector of this point also points radially outwards. This means that both $r$ and $n$ have the same direction. Also, you know that the magnitude of $r$ is $a$. Why you know that? Well, $r$ is the position of each point on the sphere, and by definition each point is at a distance $a$ from the origin.

Now, you have $r\cdot n = |r||n|\cos\theta$, however $\theta =0$ since they're paralel, $|n|=1$ because $n$ is unitary and $|r| = a$ by the preceding discussion. So $r\cdot n = a$. Now you'll get:

$$\int_S r \cdot n \ = a \int_S 1$$

And recall that the integral of the constant function $1$ over any surface gives you the area of the surface which you know is $4\pi a^2$. So you get:

$$\int_S r \cdot n = 4\pi a^3$$

Comment: Super, thank you very much.